# Adding mathjax in weebley

Tags: html, css, latex, mathjax

In weebley I   want to write the website content as LATEX so I have found a [link](http://mathtype.weebly.com/index.html) that is saying that I will have to insert a  code (`<script
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>`) in Design mode( click Edit HTML/CSS and add this before the  tag).

I have found the HTML/CSS mode but didn't get `<head>` tag. I see there `header`.  Where I will have to add the mathjax link?

[image]

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 1):

We have an article about that, but I've just updated it and the changes aren't live yet. In short, you need to add the MathJax script to your Page Layouts (tall-header.html, and others), not the CSS as you have shown in the screen shot.

Here's the article, so keep checking back for updates: [Adding MathJax to Weebly](http://www.dessci.com/en/support/MathType/works_with.asp#!target=weebly)

Also, here's a PDF version of the article, with changes already made: [PDF of article](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17008533/math_in_weebly.pdf)